# Плавное изменения backgroud'а на кнопке по её нажатию

Tags: qt5, qml, qtquick

Есть кнопка, на кнопке прикреплено 3 изображения. То есть кнопка меняет свой вид по событиям. По наведению курсора, по нажатию и по тому как курсор выходит за рамки кнопки. И мне надо, чтобы изображение (то-есть `background` на кнопке) менялся в зависимости от события, только плавно. То есть по наведению курсора, он плавно сменил свой `background` на другое изображение и также по нажатию кнопку плавно изображение должно поменяться на другое.

Я сделал анимацию градиентами, думал что поможет, однако он ругается на то что я хочу впихнуть изображение в свойство (не в свойство градиента).

Прекрепляю сам [проект](https://yadi.sk/d/xYLgf6ELxs7fT) с изображениями

Я **честно** пытаюсь сам, но не получается. На *Qt Widgets* я давно написал этот проект, но заказчик просит красоту и анимацию.

Вот код, он очень прост:

```
Button {
    id: btnAnim
    width: 250
    height: 100
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: "Anim button                 " //самое костыльное позиционирование текста
    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Image {
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: {
                control.pressed ? "btn_pressed.png" : (control.hovered ? "btn_hovered.png" : "btn_state.png")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А обязательно верстать кнопку картинками? Если рисовать ее квадратами, то анимации сделать куда проще, а вот плавную смену изображения можно реализовать только через несколько контролов с разными картинками и изменяемой прозрачностью, получится довольно уродливый код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось не всё так сложно. Вся область кнопки это не **Button{}** и даже не **Rectangle{}** а просто **MouseArea{}** в этом блоке я объявил 3 блока **Image{}** в каждый блок я помесил 3 изображения (дефолтная "кнопка", наведенная кнопка и нажатая кнопка), потом в блок **state[]** я помещаю **PropertyChanges{}** и там в качестве **target** я выбираю какой изображение и прозрачность

В прицепе это всё. Сам [проект](https://yadi.sk/d/RJtsa8Y-xxxFP) я прикрепляю

Надеюсь ком-нибудь это поможет и\или будет интересно :) всем хороших и удачных проектов :)